# Sklearn method to predict number of clusters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

right now I'm looking for an `sklearn` method that does something like:

```
arr = [13,15,41,45,90,100]
print(KMeans.num_clusters(arr))
```

> Outputs 3

Comment: K-means requires you to pass the desired number of clusters. Please read more about the method and ask in [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange community as this is more of a Data Science question then programming one.

Comment: There are 30+ methods to determine number of clusters. It all depends on your view of the business problem at hand, not on a miracle "method". See R's `Nbclust` package for a full list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mean-shift clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.html). It does not require number of clusters beforehand. However, the drawback of mean shift is that it is not very efficient compared to the k-means. Since your example array is only 1 dimensional it should not be a problem. If you are going to use mean-shift with 2 or more dimensional data, be careful with the curse of dimensionality.

Comment: This seems to be making too many clusters, is there any fix to make it more consistent?

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it by increasing bandwidth!

Comment: Nice! There is also a built in function in sklearn to do that.  estimate_bandwidth